# What are the examples of results which have been proved assuming a conjecture to be both true and false?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education, big-list, conjectures

Littlewood proving that $Li(x) - \pi(x)$ changes sign infinitely often by assuming the Riemann Hypothesis. But later he was able to prove it assuming the Riemann Hypothesis is false.

I find it interesting that you could make opposite assumptions and still arrive at the same result.

What are the examples of other results which have been proved assuming a conjecture to be true and also assuming the same conjecture to be false.

Comment: You could say that any proof which looks at several cases is of this type. You first assume Case 1 is true and show the result holds, then you assume Case 1 is false and show that the result still holds.